# what should i use listview or table layout

Tags: android

i have two tables  named student and attendance  in  database . i want to take the student_

id and student_name fields from student table and add one additional view at run time that

will be a switch view so swiping of switchview will  used for that specific student at that

row  to present or absent .. now my question is either i should use table layout to represent

these 3 views in a single row or use listview for this purpose .because i have hundreds of students in student table , also give some idea how to handle the events of switch view if u suggest listview .

Comment: If you ever have hundreds of anything you need to display, a `ListView` is what you want.

Comment: ok but in that case i want only to use the switch view to enable but in listview can we disable the cliking property of a row so that it looks like a row in table?

Comment: As long as you don't add a listener for item click, nothing will happen when you click a row.

Comment: yes u are right but how it will look like when i swipe the switch view and a complete row will also  clicked .. regardless of this is its clicking property handle or not .